# Spring boot JWT with React. How to send User credentials as Json using React and Axios to Spring boot application

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, jwt

I am trying to send user login credentials from Reactjs as Json using Axios to spring boot application: however, it is not working. But when I tried it in postman it work find and even generated a toke and send it back.

**Below is a test react code I am using. I have use both method and none work**

```
const loginInfo = {
"username": "root",
"password": 'password'
};

class EmployeeAuthenticate {
employeeLogin(username, password) {
    return axios
        .post(`http://localhost:8080/login`, JSON.stringify(loginInfo),
            { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            }
        ).then(res => {
            console.log(res)
        }).catch(error => console.log(error))
}
}

employeeLogin(username, password) {
    return axios
        .post(`http://localhost:8080/login`, {
            "username": "root",
            "password": "password"
            },
            { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            }
        ).then(res => {
            console.log(res)
        }).catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

**Below is the method I am trying to send the post request to.**

```
public class JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
private final ApplicationJwtSecurityKey securityKey;

public JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
                                        ApplicationJwtSecurityKey securityKey) {
    super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url));
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    this.securityKey = securityKey;

}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    try {
        System.out.println("User name is " + request.getParameter("username") + " Param name ");
        EmployeeAuthenticate employeeAuthenticateRequest = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), EmployeeAuthenticate.class);
        Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                employeeAuthenticateRequest.getUsername(),
                employeeAuthenticateRequest.getPassword()
        );
        // Will check if the username exist and if it exist then it will check if the password is correct
        return authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

**Below is the Security configuration in WebSecurityConfig Class**

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthFilter("/login", authenticationManager(), securityKey), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/employee-management/**").hasAnyRole(ROLE_ADMIN.name())
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
}
```

This is the errors message I keep getting

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: No content to map due to end-of-input
at [Source: (org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream); line: 1, column: 0]
```

I debug it in chrome when I send the request and this is the result

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I saw you got "Request method OPTIONS". In my opinions, it is about preflight request (a request before post was called). Did you have some research about CORS?

Comment: Try to enable CORS on your Spring application `https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/`

Comment: Singgih Suryo P and Joao Dantas thank for pointing out the CORS and the second call "Request method Options" that was made. I actually know about CORS and I did enable it in my backend to allow any incoming request; however, I forget that I did defined **proxy** in package.json file which cause an issue to make a second request. What I end up doing was, I keep the _**proxy**_ and  remove **http://localhost** from Axios and it work. Thank your so much!!!